# How to fetch Dataset if there is null value in some column of the table

Tags: c#, sql-server

Some of my fields are null and I want to view the remaining details which are in other columns. I am calling a store procedure and getting the Dataset. But SP is returning Dataset for only those ID's which have all the column fields full. Otherwise it's not returning any thing. Is there anyway I can fetch the details in spite of having null values.

Comment: Show us your query first.

Comment: Either change your current query or make a new one.

Comment: It sounds like you need an OUTER JOIN, but you need to post your code and give a little more information.

Comment: Better you post your actual query, if you have INNER join , and if fields having null value than you will not get records from other table, so if that is the case than better to use OUTER JOIN which will ignore null value, and always you will get records which you are expecting(with NULL)

Comment: I got my error. The fields were foreign key that were having null values.